# Require stylesheets and inject them to html as link tag with browserify

Tags: javascript, html, css, browserify

I wanna try using browserify for building my projects. It looks pretty cool that I can require js files using relative paths, then bundle and minify that files alltogether. But it remains unclear to me yet, if I can automatically add that bundle to html as

`<script src=".../.../bundle.min.js"></script>`

And, if I can do a similar trick with css - somehow require css files, including vendor ones, bundle and minify that files and inject that bundled css to html head as `<link>` tag, not `<style>`.

Is that possible? If so how? Or, maybe such an idea itself is just a misunderstanding of how projects should be built? If so, where am I mistaking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check [browserify-css](https://github.com/cheton/browserify-css) It allows the minification, inserting in another bundle css file.
But the main function of browserify is to build the JavaScript files into a single main one, but not css processing. It just is not created for css.

Comment: I've taken a look at browserify-css, but AFAIK it inserts css via <style> tag, amiright?

Comment: @TristanTzara yes, unfortunately this is a limitation. If you need a final standalone css file, use gulp-concat.

Comment: So, looks like browserify itself won't help me to do such thing and I should better use gulp-concat + gulp-minify-css + gulp-inject and leave browserify alone?

Comment: @TristanTzara Yes, I think this is the right decision. The main function of browserify is to build the JavaScript files into a single main one, but not css processing. It just is not created for css.

Answer (score 1):

I use Microsoft Ajax Minifier to just that.  I create the bundled scripts just for what in need for both css and js.  It has a -pretty option that just copies the files but not minify to make it easier r to debug.

Order of files matters.

On CSS, be careful if you are using embedded icons such as background-icon:url("somefile.jpg").  Your images have to be placed relative to the path used in the css where ever the bundled files end up, not where your page is.

Comment: This tool can be used stand alone or, as in my case, by Visual Studio in the build process.   I end up with 4 files.  1 for plugins such as jquery and jquery.ui, 1 for css plugins that goes with the first file, my css and my javascript specific to the page.