# Is it possible to bundle js and css files separately using browserify

Tags: browserify

The command I'm using is

```
browserify -t browserify-css src\app.js > bundle.js
```

And css files that are traversed end up as text blobs in the bundle.js files which ultimately get appended as style tags to the head when loaded in a browser.

Is it be possible to output both a bundle.js and bundle.css file, where the bundle.css is just the concatenation of all css files that were traversed?

The src\app.js in this example contains only one require

```
require( 'app.css' );
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34459148/require-stylesheets-and-inject-them-to-html-as-link-tag-with-browserify i think this might be what you are looking for

Comment: That is disappointing. So far I'm not as enamored with Browserify as much as the rest of the web community seems to be.

Comment: @user1834059 Something like https://github.com/undoZen/css-linkify might be helpful

Comment: @PrayagVerma looks like css-linkify works similarly to browserify-css which also doesn't have the desired output, which again is a single js file that does not do anything silly like dynamically inserting link tags, and a single css file which contains the concatenated contents of all the css files traversed while bundling. Browserify is very node centric in that it creates only one js file and inserts any none js files inline in the js with hacky shims to get it to work in the browser.

Comment: @user1834059 Did a bit of research, what you require (a separate JS & CSS bundle) can be achieved using browserify plugin [parcelify](https://github.com/rotundasoftware/parcelify) but not in the way you want (aka doing a direct `require` of CSS files). Instead, you will have to mention those CSS files in the `style` attribute of `package.json` of the project itself (For third party npm modules included as dependencies, if their `package.json` contains a `style` field, those files will also be included in that CSS bundle). I have created an example here - https://github.com/pra85/angular-seed

Comment: I filed an issue/question with browserify-css and it looks it has a little traction https://github.com/cheton/browserify-css/issues/32. The parcelify solution will not work for me because this one repository creates a number of smaller artifacts. I'll answer this question here when/if the separateCSS option is implemented. Thanks for the suggestions though.

Comment: FWIW, `webpack` has an [`ExtractTextPlugin`](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin) that does exactly what you want, assuming you're okay with adding webpack to your build task.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [sheetify](https://github.com/stackcss/sheetify) transform, which outputs code that uses [insert-css](https://github.com/substack/insert-css). Then, use the [css-extract](https://github.com/stackcss/css-extract) browserify plugin to extract the insert-css calls into a separate file.

```sh
browserify -t sheetify/transform -p [ css-extract -o bundle.css ] index.js \
  -o bundle.js
```